# how to convert json objects sepeted by comma into object

Tags: javascript

i have a string of 2 json object like this:

```
var param = '{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"},{"key3":"value3"}';
```

how can i separate into 2 object like this in javascript..

```
 var objA = {"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"};
 var objB = {"key3":"value3"};
```

Answer (score 3):

As simple as this - make an array from this objects

```
var param = '{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"},{"key3":"value3"}'; 
var obj = JSON.parse('[' + param + ']');
var objA = obj[0];
var objB = obj[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
var data = JSON.parse("[" + param "]");
objA = data[0];
objB = data[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

You JSON string is wrong. Change your code to

```
var param = '[{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"},{"key3":"value3"}]';
var jsonArr = JSON.parse(param);
for(var i in jsonArr) {
    var jsonObj = jsonArr[i];
    // jsonObj is your required object
}
```

See this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/uqtyX/2/) here.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do it with objects like this;

```
var param = '{"objA": {"key1": "value1","key2": "value2"}, "objB": {"key3": "value3"}}',
    obj = JSON.parse(param),
    objA = obj.objA,
    objB = obj.objB;

console.log([obj, objA, objB]);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aeoril/z8wqE/)